# problem with selenium firefox on google colab

Tags: ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, firefox, google-colaboratory

i am using google colab and i had to install firefox to use it as selenium webdriver .
first i get this error from selenium
`WebDriverException: Message: Process unexpectedly closed with status 1`

i install firefox on colab with '!apt install firefox' command but below is part of result message :

```
Preparing to unpack …/firefox_1%3a1snap1-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb … 
=> Installing the firefox snap 
==> Checking connectivity with the snap store 
===> System doesn’t have a working snapd, skipping
```

run firefox give this error :

```
 Command ‘/usr/bin/firefox’ requires the firefox snap to be installed. Please install it with: snap install firefox
```

and executing ‘!snap install firefox’ also give error:

```
error: cannot communicate with server: Post “http://localhost/v2/snaps/firefox”: dial unix /run/snapd.socket: connect: no such file or directory
```

everything was working fine last month
what is the solution for this ? is there anything i can do ?